# Why is the following type declaration and/or instatiation not working in Julia 1.0?

Tags: types, type-conversion, julia, type-constructor

I have a circle type

```
struct Circle{T <: Real}
  # radius is a subtype of
  # the real number approximation types
  R::T
  # The center is a named pair of real
  # number approximation types
  C::NamedTuple{T, T}
end
```

which I would like to instantiate with

```
circles = NamedTuple(
    A = Circle(1, ( 1,  1)),
    B = Circle(1, ( 2,  2))
  )
```

which produces the error

```
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching Circle(::Int64, ::Tuple{Int64,Int64})
Closest candidates are:
  Circle(::T<:Real, ::NamedTuple{T<:Real,T<:Real}) where T<:Real
```

Why does this error occur and what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Named tuples](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Core.NamedTuple) are parametrized by names and a tuple:

```
julia> struct Circle{T <: Real}
         R::T
         C::NamedTuple
         Circle(r::T, c::NamedTuple{N,Tuple{T,T}}) where {N, T <: Real} = new{T}(r,c)
       end

julia> Circle(1, (a=1, b=2))
Circle{Int64}(1, (a = 1, b = 2))
```

If you want to construct a `Circle` with a tuple, you can provide a default mapping:

```
julia> function Circle(r::T, c::Tuple{T,T}) where {T <: Real}
           a, b = c
           return Circle(r, (a=a, b=b))
       end
Circle

julia> Circle(1, (1, 2))
Circle{Int64}(1, (a = 1, b = 2))
```

If you don't need named tuples, you can use regular tuples:

```
julia> struct Circle{T <: Real}
         R::T
         C::Tuple{T, T}
       end

julia> Circle(1, (1, 2))
Circle{Int64}(1, (1, 2))
```